# getElementById('___').innerHTML Destroying Element's ID?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks a navigation menu, the title changes to that title and the main content changes too. I'd rather try and avoid using frames for this.

```
$('op').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML=this.innerHTML + ((this.innerHTML.indexOf("'s")==this.innerHTML.length-2) ? " " : "'s ") + this.parentNode.id + " | Le Lepids";
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=document.getElementById(this.innerHTML + '_' + this.parentNode.id).innerHTML;
});
// If the code looks ugly and you can't read it, just tell me.
```

What happens, though, is the title changes perfectly every time, but the content only changes once.

For instance it'll work fine the first time, then not work any other time after that.

Why is this so? Does it destroy the id 'content'? I'm not using outterHTML though. And if dose, why does the title change fine?

---

EDIT: Okay, so I think I got it fixed with a few lines of PHP.
But I'm still wondering why it won't work on my site while what Mia DiLorenzo made works perfectly fine... the code is exactly the same other than variable names.

Comment: without your HTML structure, we arent really able to help

Comment: The code is very unreadable.  It takes quite awhile to decipher what you the code attempts to do.  And, without your HTML and a description of what it's supposed to do, we can't tell you why it doesn't work the way you expect or suggest something better.  If you show us the HTML, I'm sure we can make it much, much, much better than it is.

Comment: Are you updating the variable names the same way? They have a relationship, for example, when I wrote `div id="container"`, I have to write `container` below (change_, modify_, alter_container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but I wrote something anyway http://jsfiddle.net/69FDT/1/

I changed `$('op')` to `$('p')` and added some divs to match your Javascript line that changes `content`. Did you mean something else?

```
<div id="container">
    <div>Click on these words</div>
      <p>change</p>
      <p>modify</p>
      <p>alter</p>
    <br>
      <div id='title'>Title</div>
      <div id='content'>content</div>
<br>
      <div id="change_container">change placeholder div</div>
      <div id="modify_container">modify placeholder div</div>
      <div id="alter_container">alter placeholder div</div>
    </div>​
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for. It still doesn't work on my page though.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't yet a full answer (we need your HTML for that), but I think this information is on the step to an answer and it can't be conveyed in a comment.

In pseudo-code (to make it more understandable), this is what your code is doing:

For the `#content` item:

1. Get the innerHTML of the clicked on `op` element.
2. Add `'_'` to that innerHTML.
3. Add the parentNode.id of the clicked on `op` element.
4. With that manufactured id, do a `document.getElementById()` on it to find the object.
5. Get the innerHTML of that object and put that innerHTML into the `#content` item.

For the `#title` item:

1. Get the innerHTML of the clicked on `op` element.
2. If that HTML ends with `"'s"`, then add `" "` onto the innerHTML, otherwise add `"'s"`.
3. Add the parentNode.id onto that.
4. Add `" | Le Lepids"` onto that.
5. Set the innerHTML of the `#title` item to that result.

I can think of several reasons why the `#content` item might always get set to the same item or why it might only work sometimes, but we'd have to see your actual HTML to know for sure which happens when or why.